# Switching to US English msmdsrv.rll Analysis Services

Tags: sql-server-2008, devexpress, ssas, olap, olap-cube

I'm using Analysis Services for a web application I'm building, I have my Analysis Service running, I included a PivotGrid from DevExpress on a web page, I checked on SQLServer that my cube is displaying information, and it does, but when I run my application the PivotGrid doesn't display the data, I checked the logs on the EventViewer and I get the following error:

> The resource file 'msmdsrv.rll' for locale '1034' could not be loaded.
>   Switching to US English (1033) if available.

Obviously this is about the language the cube is trying to find, I changed the language to English (United States) in the dropdown list included at the top of SQLServer but I still getting the error, any suggestion?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally I found the problem, I was thinking the problem comes from the SqlServer installation but it doesn't, I just change the region from my computer and that was all. I have answered my own question because probably somebody else could have the same problem.

Regards